# Where's my Minecraft world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc

In Minecraft I have this world called `I CAN READ YOUR MIIIIIIIIIND`. I can see it in the singleplayer list. But, when I go to `.minecraft/saves` I can't find it. The same thing happens with MCEdit.

I need to share this world. Could anyone tell me were I can find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes, a world has a different world name than that of its in-game name.

You can see the folder name of any world by looking at the name next to the date. As you can see in this picture, the title of the world is different to its folder name, which can be found next to the red arrow.

[image: picture showing this difference]

Simply look in the 'saves' folder for the folder name of your world.

*(Note I am using English - Australian as my language, ignore the Australian spin on the gamemode)*

Comment: Love the "Australian English" haha

Comment: @Ben Give it a try, if you know all the slang it's pretty funny.

Comment: @AngusAtkinson oh, I already do - as an Aussie I find it awesome haha